# Secure Connection Failed

Tags: java, selenium

I am having a problem in executing my test with converted Junit WebDriver Backed. When I execute this test by java file its stopped on the first screen and after few seconds it shows me this error "Secure Connection Failed " the website is running over https, when I execute the code from Selenium IDE it works correctly. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a self-signed SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this error in selenium 2.0 web driver?

If this is in selenium RC, check if this helps in any way:

http://aboutselenium.blogspot.com/2011/10/dealing-with-ssl-certificate-error-or.html